# Ionic 5: best practice to get the built platform

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm writing an app using Ionic 5, Angular and Cordova. I would like to get the "platform" variable used to build my application (i.e. the argument used in a command like "ionic cordova build android).

Unfortunately, all I found on the web was the Platform service (https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/platform), useful but not quite what I needed (e.g. platform.is('android') can return true if the application runs on a web app on an android phone, on a browser on an android phone or if I click F12 on chrome...).
What I need is to find the platform the application was built for.

The best way I found to achieve the result, was to add "build:before" hook in my ionic.config.json file

```js
  "hooks": {
    "build:before": "scripts/build-before.js",
    "build:after": "scripts/build-after.js"
   }
```

and change the constant in a service before building

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
var process = require('process');
var fs = require('fs');

let input=process.argv;

let android="android";
let browser="browser";
let ios="ios";
let platformFile="MYFILE"


module.exports = function() {
    let nbArgs=input.length;
    let platform;
    for(let i=0;i<nbArgs;i++){
        if(input[i]==android){
            platform=android;
        }
        if(input[i]==browser){
            platform=browser;
        }
        if(input[i]==ios){
            platform=ios;
        }
    }

    let file = fs.readFileSync(platformFile, 'utf8');
    let replacement="MYSTART '"+platform+"';";
    let result = file.replace(/MYREGEX/g, replacement);
    fs.writeFileSync(platformFile, result);

    console.log("Service updated with platform: "+platform);
}
```

Then in the build:after I restore the file as it was (to avoid to commit the file on GIT after each build...).

I added the code in case someone has the same issue and looks for a quick workaround.

My question is: does anyone know of an official/smarter way to achieve the result?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure of what your goal is, but detecting the platform where the app is running is way easier than that. For example, if you want to know if the app is being executed on an *Android mobile device*, you could use the following condition:

```
if(this.platform.is('mobile') && this.platform.is('android')) {
  // ...
}
```

In a similar way, you can check if the device is a `desktop`, a `pwa`, ... or any other combination based on the following list:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/platform#platforms

```
android:    a device running Android
capacitor:  a device running Capacitor
cordova:    a device running Cordova
desktop:    a desktop device
electron:   a desktop device running Electron
hybrid:     a device running Capacitor or Cordova
ios:        a device running iOS
ipad:       an iPad device
iphone:     an iPhone device
mobile:     a mobile device
mobileweb:  a web browser running in a mobile device
phablet:    a phablet device
pwa:        a PWA app
tablet:     a tablet device
```

Comment: My main goal is being able to detect what was the cordova platform targeted by the app build.
This is because I use 2 plugins to do the same thing on different platforms, but that conflict with each others.

Comment: @Fra I think the answer above will allow you to do that :)

Comment: Thank you, I guess that's the closer to the goal that's indeed also in the various Ionuc docs :)